# Automatizar deploy no Jboss pelo Jenkins?

Tags: jboss, deploy, jenkins

Qual seria a melhor maneira de se fazer um deploy no Jboss EAP via Jenkins ?

Após a conclusão do build, caso ocorra com sucesso, gostaria de fazer o deploy da minha aplicação, seria melhor via plugin ou criar alguns script (Executando no pós build do Jenkins).

Atualmente faço esse deploy manualmente, via console do Jboss.

Answer (score 1):

Edson, existem ferramentas especializadas em Deploy automatizado que facilitam demais a sua vida pois disponibilizam um leque imenso de possibilidades e formas de trabalhar o seu deploy. Hoje utilizo o Jenkins como orquestrador de build e tem me atendido bem, o que tenho lido sobre utilizá-lo como ferramenta de deploy não é nada bom, dê uma olhada aqui: https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/tools

Aconselho você dar uma olhada no IBM Urbancode Deploy, BitBucket, Capistrano, DeployBot, ElasticBox, JuJu...
Existem muitas, procure a que mais se adéqua ao seu ambiente.